# Can't execute file with CMD under Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

I'm currently trying to run a file located at `C:\Chocolatey\lib\ScriptCs.0.5.1\tools\scriptcs\scriptcs.exe`

Originally I tried popping up a CMD and running the command scripts as it should already be on my path. Problem is I get a popup error saying:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ZSmith\Application Data\scriptcs\scriptcs.exe 
is not a valid Win32 application
```

and it outputs *"Access Denied"* to the CMD. After this I ran

```
find -name 'scriptcs.exe'
```

just to check where it installed to. The default install directory is `C:\Chocolatey\lib\ScriptCs.0.5.1\tools\scriptcs\scriptcs.exe` as I've said. Attempting to run it from there produces the same error.

Perhaps I'm failing to understand the administrative principals of Windows XP and there's a conflict there but I believe I have complete admin control of my computer (barring access to the admin account as this is a work computer). I did recently install Cygwin. I'd not tried running `scriptcs` before that on its own. Cygwin could possibly be causing a conflict but I doubt it.

Comment: What script are you running? it appears that a step in the script you are running is attempting to run `%appdata%\scriptcs\scriptcs.exe`.

Comment: The error's completely unrelated. I'm closing the question. Turns out there's no x86 compatibility for ScriptCS. There's no documentation on it. Had to submit an issue on Github to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/216), you need to build a 32-bit version from source.

Comment: Thank you but I already mentioned that in the comments. That ticket's basically inactive. See the ticket I submitted here: https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/367

Comment: Your ticket was marked as a duplicate of that one. The ScriptCS sources are available, and there's a build.cmd in there. If you have Visual Studio installed I guess you could build a 32-bit EXE yourself, which is what is suggested as the solution. Otherwise look around for someone who's already done so and shared the pre-built executable.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, I was trying to use an application with this problem; it turns out that the build had been reconfigured to no longer support Windows XP.  Getting an older build which still had the XP compatibility fixed it for me.

So, getting a 32-bit build is *not* a sufficient fix if the build is not also configured to use the `_xp` toolset.

The error is kind of insidious because the "Access Denied" error message is somewhat misleading and common google hits on this error message suggest the download was corrupted or something.